How to represent following GF2EX as output polynomial?
I'm having this problem, where after calling the berlekamp function (GF2EXFactoring.h) the output is in a unknown format.
// x^n - 1 mod 2^pow
int pow = 2;
int n = 12;

GF2X P;
BuildIrred(P, pow);
GF2E::init(P);

GF2EX prvok2;
SetCoeff(prvok2, 0, -1);
SetCoeff(prvok2, n, 1);

cout << P << endl;
cout << prvok2 << endl;

vec_pair_GF2EX_long faktory;

berlekamp(faktory, prvok2);
cout << faktory;

The output from this code is the following:
[1 1 1]
[[1] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [1]]
[[[[1] [1]] 4] [[[0 1] [1]] 4] [[[1 1] [1]] 4]]

The output should be a vector of factors. In the second element we have:
[[[0 1] [1]] 4]

How can we have a polynomial in the position where [] or [1] should be?
Or if it's even allowed how can we get this output to the form:
x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + ... + x^n

Do I have to use another function to get into a pure [] or [1]?
